# Selenium Run Times

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to figure out what is the correct syntax to record the time it takes to run a test script in Selenium IDE.

How do I record the start and end times in the script (using HTML)?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, it does do this already. In fact if any test runner does not record that, I would log a feature request  :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to execute some javascript statements.

```
storeEval | javascript{var startTime=new Date().getTime(); startTime;} | startingtime
setSpeed | 500
open | http://www.google.com/
setSpeed | 0
storeEval | javascript{var endTime=new Date().getTime(); endTime;} | endingtime
echo | ${startingtime}
echo | ${endingtime}
```

Edit code for elapsed time:

```
storeEval | javascript{startTime=new Date().getTime(); startTime;} | startingtime
setSpeed | 500
open | http://www.google.com/
setSpeed | 0
storeEval | javascript{endTime=new Date().getTime(); endTime;} | endingtime
storeEval | javascript{var duration = endTime - startTime;duration;} | dur
echo | ${startingtime}
echo | ${endingtime}
echo | ${dur}
```